# Should I add .idea/jarRepositories.xml to gitignore?

Tags: android, android-studio, gitignore

Should I add .idea/jarRepositories.xml to gitignore?
It was generated after updating Android Studio to 4.0

Comment: I had the same question, and found that [it has only redundant information about remote jar repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63544057/9298629).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As illustrated by [this PR](https://github.com/expo/expo/pull/8979), you can add `.idea/jarRepositories.xml` to `.gitignore` (and `git rm --cached .idea/jarRepositories.xml`)

> - [`gitignore.io` with IntelliJ preset](https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore/api/intellij) removes the file
> - I guess we're using the auto-import feature and don't need to track this file